# How to sketch a surface

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, graphing-functions

I was wondering if I could receive help on how to sketch the surface (x-2)^2 - y^2 - (z+1)^2 = 0. I'm unsure of where to start, should I calculate the intercepts and estimate the dimensions?

Comment: Find some points you know for certain are on it, e.g.  $(2,0,-1)$; see if you have any symmetries; try to classify it as a quadric surface. Or check out geogebra.org/3d or some such.

Comment: Your surface is a $2$-dimensional submanifold of the $3$-dimensional euclidian space. Set $z=0$ so you know how it looks "from above", i.e. the $x,y$-perspective, then set $y=0$ so you know how it looks from the $x,z$ perspective and finally $x=0$ so you get a view from the $y,z$ perspective.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quadric surface.  In particular, it is a degenerate [hyperboloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid) -- a [conical surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conical_surface).  The apex is at $(2,0,-1)$.  Notice that you can move the negative terms to the other side,
$$  (x-2)^2 = y^2 + (z+1)^2  \text{,}  $$
showing that for each choice of $x$, you obtain a circle in the plane of points having that $x$ coordinate.  This tells us the axis of revolution of the surface is parallel to the $x$ axis (the circles are traced out as $y$ and $z$ vary).